# Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: Id.Iam getting this error for the below trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, error

```
trigger AmountOpportunity on Opportunity (after insert) {
    Map<id,Opportunity> oldmap = Trigger.OldMap;
    Map<id,Opportunity> newmap = Trigger.NewMap;
    List<Id> Ids= new List<Id>();
    if(Trigger.isinsert){
    for(id oid:newmap.keyset()){
        if(newmap.get(oid).Amount>0){          
            Account acc = [select id,name,AnnualRevenue from Account where id =:oid.Accountid]; 
            acc.AnnualRevenue=acc.AnnualRevenue+newmap.get(oid).Amount;
            update acc;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it still an open question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this `oid.Accountid`

Since `oid` being of datatype `Id` you can't get `Accountid` from it. To do so use `newmap.get(oid).Accountid`. So your code should be

```
trigger AmountOpportunity on Opportunity (after insert) {
    Map<id,Opportunity> oldmap = Trigger.OldMap;
    Map<id,Opportunity> newmap = Trigger.NewMap;
    List<Id> Ids= new List<Id>();
    if(Trigger.isinsert){
    for(id oid:newmap.keyset()){
        if(newmap.get(oid).Amount>0){          
            Account acc = [select id,name,AnnualRevenue from Account where id =:newmap.get(oid).Accountid]; 
            acc.AnnualRevenue=acc.AnnualRevenue+newmap.get(oid).Amount;
            update acc;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually oid is the account I'd do just use oid by itself. Then there is the use of needless code and DML inside for loop

Answer (score 0):

SO  couple of errors. Always query and DML should be outside of for loop else you will hit governor limits

```
trigger AmountOpportunity on Opportunity (after insert) 
{
    Map<id,Opportunity> oldmap = Trigger.OldMap;
    Map<id,Opportunity> newmap = Trigger.NewMap;
    List<Id> Ids= new List<Id>();
    if(Trigger.isinsert)
    {
        // first collect all the account ids into a new set variable 
        set<Id> setAccountid = new set<Id>();
        for(Opportunity opp:newmap.values())
        {
            if(opp.Amount>0 && opp.AccountId != null)
            {          
                setAccountid.add(opp.AccountId);
            }
        }
        //now based on set variable query all the account records.
        map<Id, Account> mapAccount = new map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, AnnualRevenue 
                                                              FROM Account WHERE Id IN: setAccountid]);
        for(Opportunity opp:newmap.values())
        {
            //check if the opportunity account is present in map then update that Account 
            if(opp.Amount>0 && opp.AccountId != null && mapAccount.containsKey(opp.AccountId))
            {
                mapAccount.get(opp.AccountId).AnnualRevenue = mapAccount.get(opp.AccountId).AnnualRevenue + opp.Amount; 
            }
        }
        //update Account list 
        update mapAccount.values();
    }
}
```